# .htaccess changes in WordPress that would add aliases to URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to add aliases to an existing .htaccess taht was generated with WordPress. So essentially I want to keep the current URLs as they are, but overwrite some of them with a different value that will make the URL act as an alias.

So if I go to http //mysite.com/test-post/ I want it to go to the home page, but still have "test-post/" as the URL. If possible I want to have a per URL basis of adding this to the .htaccess.

The existing .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up... firstly thank you for all the feedback on this, but I was being an idiot and would have shot myself in the foot if I went ahead with this, because I would have called content using AJAX from URLs that would all just go to the homepage.

So what I did was disable permalinks in WordPress and then used the "nice names" that WP saves for you in the DB as nice URLs. And then redirected everything to the homepage using some basic .htaccess rules I found online.

So once everything was redirecting to home and I associated the nice names with the post IDs I used the PURL jQuery library to resolve the fake URLs to the correct content.

Answer (score 0):

Intially set permalink settings as post name. Settings -> Premalinks.

Go to the page in which you want to change the ending portion of url, click on edit which is just below the title and change the name there.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add unique exceptions like you need but each post that you want to append its /%postname%/ to will need one added to this 301 redirect snippet.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com/test-post$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/test-post$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

You can use a rewrite rule that uses ^$ to represent the root and rewrite that to your /test-post page, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /test-post [L]
```